# AngularJS - How to set transformParams for query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

I'm trying to properly encode query params on angular with the code below:

```
getAccount = function (accountEmail, accountCreationDate) {

      var data = {
        accountEmail: accountEmail,
        accountCreationDate: accountCreationDate
      };

      return $http.get('/administration/account.json', {params: $filter('noBlankValues')(data)}).then(
        function (result) {
          $log.debug('getAccount result: ' + JSON.stringify(result.data));
          return result.data.result;
        }
      );
    };
```

accountCreationDate is an ISO-8601 string (e.g. "2014-03-20T14:56:01.691+01:00"). According to [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) I'm passing params as an object, but in the frame I've the following "strange" query output:

```
?accountCreationDate=2014-03-20T14:56:01.691%2B01:00&accountEmail=test@test.com
```

i.e. the date '+' was encoded but not the rest of the object. Do you have any idea of what is going wrong and how to fix that?

PS: I know I can write manually the encoded query string, but I'm looking a more user-friendly solution.

Comment: By output you mean the url used to make the request, right? What output do you expect?

Comment: Right, I'm expecting that:
?accountCreationDate=2014-03-20T14%3A56%3A01.691%2B01%3A00&accountEmail=test%40test.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was solved by using the following transform function:

```
var transform = function () {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      transformRequest: function (obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
          if ((typeof obj[p] !== 'undefined') &&
            (typeof obj[p] !== 'function')) {

            if (obj[p] instanceof Date) {
              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p].toISOString()));
            }
            else if (obj[p] instanceof Array) {
              for (var i in obj[p]) {
                if (obj[p][i] instanceof Object) {
                  str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj[p][i])));
                } else {
                  str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p][i]));
                }
              }
            }
            else if (obj[p] instanceof Object) {
              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj[p])));
            }
            else {
              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            }
          }
        }
        return str.join('&');
      }
    }
};
```